# Insert into a table with a serial field and using its future value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE problem (
  id SERIAL,
  title VARCHAR(50),
  author VARCHAR(50),
  path TEXT,
  compiler VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`problem.id` is an auto-incremented integer.
There are ways of doing an insert without knowing its value:

```
INSERT INTO problem VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Hello World', 'unknown', '/var/www/files/problems', 'Python');
INSERT INTO problem (title, author, path, compiler) VALUES ('Hello World', 'unknown', '/var/www/files/problems', 'Python');
```

However, I would like to know the `problem.id` at insert time, so I can append it to `path`:

> /var/www/files/problems/**{id}**

Where `{id}` is the `problem.id` of the **inserted** problem.

Comment: do you want to insert record with out id correct?

Comment: You mean the path is created before the table row?

Comment: The path is where the files associated with the problem will go and, for that reason, I wanted to "know" the id that the problem will have at the moment of the insert.

Comment: If the path id is derived from id it is not necessary to save it. Just build it at query time: `select '/var/www/files/problems/' || id from problem`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use combination of [`nextval` and `lastval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-sequence.html):

```
INSERT INTO problem VALUES (
   nextval('problem_id_seq'), 
   'Hello World',
   'unknown', 
   '/var/www/files/problems/' || lastval(), 
   'Python'
);
```

Call to `nextval` is exactly what Postgres uses as the default value for `SERIAL` fields. So it is possible to write the statement without the explicit `nextval` call:

```
INSERT INTO problem VALUES (
   DEFAULT, 
   'Hello World',
   'unknown', 
   '/var/www/files/problems/' || lastval(), 
   'Python'
);
```